# How many different choice of non-empty sets are there given sum of set sizes

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets such that $A \subseteq B$ and $|A|+|B|=8$. How many possible sets $U$ are there for all possible sets of $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subseteq U\subseteq B$?

The answer is 127, which suggests that perhaps there is an easy solution. However, I can't figure it out.

Edit: The initial question made it seem like $A$ and $B$ were fixed sets. I apologize for the ambiguity. $A$ and $B$ are not fixed sets. The question asks to find all possible sets $U$ for all possible sets of $A$ and $B$ that satisfy the given criteria.

Comment: For $A=B$ with $|A|=|B|=4$, there is only one such set $U$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Why must $|A|=|B|=4$? You can also have $|A|=3, |B|=5$ in which case you would have $|B-A|=2$.

Comment: I didn't say that you must have $|A|=|B|=4$. This was just one counterexample. In the current formulation of the question, $A$ and $B$ are fixed and the statement is claimed for any fixed sets $A$ and $B$, and thus in particular also for the case $|A|=|B|=4$. Perhaps you intended to count the possible sets $U$ for all possible sets $A$ and $B$. In that case you should reformulate the question accordingly.

Comment: That's what I intended to ask, I apologize for the ambiguity. I tried to clarify it, but if you have a better suggestion please let me know, as English is not my first language.

Comment: No worries. If you substantially change a question such that existing valid answers become invalid, it's good practice to mark the edit as such so as not to make the now invalid answers look wrong.

Comment: Are you sure $|A| + |B| =8$?  Do you think maybe the question was "Together $A$ and $B$ have $8$ elements"?  Remember, $|A\cup B| \ne |A| + |B|$.  $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B|-|A\cap B|$.  ANd if $A\subset B$ then $A\cup B=B$ and $A\cap B = A$.  So if $A\subset B$ and "$A$ and $B$ have $8$ elements" then $|B| = 8$ and $|A|$ can be anything from $1$ to $8$. And $|A| + |B| \ne 8$.

Comment: I checked again, and it says $|A|+|B|=8$. I read your answer, and I am convinced that this is an error in the book.

Comment: joriki's answer may have some assumptions that are valid.  The question as written kind of doesn't make sense and even my answer makes some assumptins that if $A=\{a_1,..., a_i\}$ and $B\setminus A=\{b_1,...,b_{8-2i}\}$ that the actual *values* of the $a_k, b_k$ aren't important; that only the *indexes* count.  Which is ... well, hand-wavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you meant to imply (or forgot to state) that $A$ and $B$ are in all cases subsets of a given set $S$ with $7$ elements. In that case, since $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, any subset of $S$ with $1$ to $7$ elements can lie between $A$ and $B$. There are $2^7=128$ subsets of $S$, and all of them except the empty set can occur, for a count of $128-1=127$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as originally stated is flawed. The statement of the problem implies that $A$ and $B$ are fixed sets. For fixed $A$ and $B$ there is a $U$ such that $A\subseteq U\subseteq B$ for each subset of $B\setminus A$, so if $|A|+|B|=8$ there are $2^{|B|-|A|}=2^{8-2|A|}=4^{4-|A|}$ possible sets $U$, but that’s all that can be said on the basis of the information given.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $|A| = 1$ then $|B| = 7$.

And if $A=\{a_1\}$ for some element, $a_1$, then $B = \{a_1, b_1,....,b_6\}$ for some six elements $b_i$.  If $A \subset U \subset B$ then $U = A \cup K$ for some subset of $B\setminus A = \{b_1, .... b_6\}$.

If $|B\setminus A| = 6$ then how many possible subsets $K$  can there be?

Well, the formula is, and you should be able to argue why, is $2^6$ possible subsets.

We can generalize this.

If $A= \{a_1,a_2,..., a_i\}$ and $|A|= i$ then $|B|=8-i$. And $|B\setminus A|=8-2i$.  As $8-i\ge 1$ and $i\ge 1$ we can have $i=1,2,3,4$ and $8-i = 7,6,5,4$. And $8-2i= 6,4,2,0$.

And if we have $A \subset U \subset B$ we must have $U = A \cup K$ for some $K\subset B\setminus A$.

And there are $2^{8-2i}$ such possible $K$.

So for all possible sizes of $A$ we have there are:

$\sum_{i=1}^4 2^{8-2i}=2^6 + 2^4 + 2^2+2^1 = 64+16 + 4 + 1=85$ such options.

So either I am wrong or your book is.

Are you sure you weren't given that $|A\cup B| = 8$ or that "$A$ and $B$ have $8$ elements"?

If that were the case then $|B| = |A\cup B| = 8$ and $|B\setminus A| = 8-|A|=8-i$ and the number of such subsets $U$ is

$\sum_{i=1}^8 2^{8-i} = \sum_{k=1}^8 2^k = 2^9 - 1 = 127$.

Bear in mind.  If you are told "Together $A$ and $B$ have $8$ elements" that does *NOT* mean $|A| + |B| = 8$.  It means $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| -|A\cap B| = 8$.  ANd if $A\subset B$ that means $A\cup B = B$ and $A\cap B = A$.  So instead of having $|A| + |B| = 8$ we would have $|B| = |A| + |B| - |A| = 8$.  Which would mean $|B|=8$ and $|A|=1,....., 8$.

===

Also the wording is ... off.

"Let A and B be two non-empty sets such that..." usually means $A$ and $B$ are *fixed*, and we can't take the cases.  $|A|=k$ and $|B|=8-k$ and $|B\setminus A|= 8-2k$ and $k$ is fixed. The only thing variable is $K:K\subset B\setminus A$ and the will be exactly $2^{8-2k}$ possble $U = A\cup K$, where $k$ is a fixed value.

In the above, I took the liberty of assuming $A$ and $B$ weren't fixed but could vary in size but the *content* of the elements wouldn't matter, only size would.